# How to get a list of urls from a LinkExtractor() or scrapy.link.Link object? (Solved)

Tags: python, url, hyperlink, scrapy, extract

I have a crawler that I want to use to extract all urls on a website into a list of strings. I am using `LinkExtractor().extract_links(response)` for this task. Even though it solves the problem of finding all the urls on a website they are returned in a list of `scrapy.link.Link` objects. Even though the urls are stored in this object I can't find an elegant way to extract the urls or documentation on scrapy Link objects.

turning the scrapy Link object into a string I get the following:

```
Link(url='https://example.com', text='', fragment='', nofollow=True)
```

I could slice my way to get the url from here. But I can't help thinking that there has to be a better solution.

**Edit:** Solved, the urls can be extracted from a scrapy Links object by simply using `Links.url`

Comment: you'll want to use list comprehension. I'm not familiar with the scrapy module, so writing this as a comment rather than an answer.  `[linkObj.url for linkObj in xyz]` where xyz is your list that is returned.  This should create a list of just the URLs

Comment: This is also alternative plan, but was wondering, since there is no documentation for scrapy.link.Link objects if someone familiar with scrapy would know how to access the url part of the object, would make it much more elegant.

Comment: You can almost certainly get the url attribute out of the object with dot notation as I have used. It is unlikely they have a way for the `extract_links` function to return just the url.

Comment: It also took me about 1 minute to find the object definition for a Link object which should tell you everything you need to know. https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/link.py

Comment: Many thanks! it works if I just do Link.url! I thought I had already tried this...